Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API: Unauthenticated Error in Production but Works in Development
I'm using the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API in my ASP.NET Core web application, and it works perfectly in my local development environment. However, when I deploy the application to the production environment, I get the following error when trying to transcribe audio:
Status(StatusCode="Unauthenticated", Detail="Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.") 
using Google.Cloud.Speech.V1;

namespace EventPrinter.Helpers
{
    public class GoogleTranscript
    {
        private readonly SpeechClient _speechClient;
        private readonly FileHelper _fileHelper;

        public GoogleTranscript(FileHelper fileHelper)
        {
            _fileHelper = fileHelper;
            string credentialPath = @$"{_fileHelper.BaseDirectory}\transcription\firebase-219721-333cab8c23c6.json";
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", credentialPath);
            
            _speechClient = SpeechClient.Create();
        }

        public async Task<string> TranscribeAsync(string filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var response = await _speechClient.RecognizeAsync(new RecognitionConfig
                {
                    Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Mp3,
                    SampleRateHertz = 48000,
                    LanguageCode = "he-IL"
                }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile(filePath));

                var transcripts = response.Results
                    .SelectMany(result => result.Alternatives)
                    .Select(alternative => $"{alternative.Transcript}")
                    .ToList();

                return transcripts.Any() ? string.Join("\n", transcripts) : "No transcription available.";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error during transcription: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}

Why am I getting an "Unauthenticated" error with Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API in production, even though it works in development with the same credentials? What else should I check or modify to resolve this?
What I've Tried:

Verified Credentials: The credentials file is correctly located in both environments.
Checked Environment Variable: Confirmed GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set properly before creating the SpeechClient.
Confirmed Permissions: The service account has the necessary Cloud Speech API Client role.
Logged Details: Printed the environment variable and file path to ensure they're correct.
Checked Network Access: No firewall or network restrictions are blocking the API in production.

What I expceted
I expected the Google Cloud Speech-to-Text API to authenticate successfully in production, just like it does in the development environment, given that both environments use the same credentials and configuration.

You should not set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in code. It is an anti-pattern and breaks. Application Default Credentials' search order. The evidence strongly suggests that you're incorrectly accessing the key when running in production but you do not provide any evidence for your assertions ("What I've tried") and so it's difficult to help.

You can also log GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault().UnderlyingCredential.GetType() which will at least show the type being used. (You could log other things as well, but that'll be a start...)
